# how can I use assertRaises() in python's unittest to catch syntaxerror?

Tags: python, exception, syntax-error, unit-testing

For example, I want to test a function which has a syntax, in my unittest class's method, can I use code as the following?

```
self.assertRaises(SyntaxError, my_function)
```

When I use this, it just appears traceback of syntax error rather than showing how many tests have passed.

Comment: can you show the error?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\wy\Desktop\python\error_library.py", line 58, in <module>
Syntax Error:     123a: c:\Users\wy\Desktop\python\error_library.py, line 58, pos 8

Comment: it's like when there is syntax error in my module which has the functions I imported, python stopped running the unittest module I ran.

Comment: Why would you ever want to assert that your code's syntax is wrong?

Comment: A unit test is your way of saying that the module is *supposed to contain a syntax error*.  Is that what you really want?  Based on your comment, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the test to run, the code must be byte compiled by the Python interpreter.  This happens when the module containing your function is imported, before the function is ever run.  It is during the compilation that the SyntaxError is generated.

In your test module, you could wrap the import statement in a try/except:

```
    raised = False
    try:
        import foo
    except SyntaxError:
        # A syntax error was generated during the import...
        raised = True
    self.assert_(raised, "'import foo' failed to raise a SyntaxError.")
```

or use one of the methods suggested by @alecxe, which look simpler and cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Following Warren Weckesser's explanation, you can test that an [import function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) is throwing an error:

```
self.assertRaises(SyntaxError, __import__, "error_library")
```

For Python 2.7 and above, [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) can/should be used instead:

```
self.assertRaises(SyntaxError, importlib.import_module, "error_library")
```